# Confidence intervals for Mahalanobis distance

Tags: r, distance, confidence-interval, mahalanobis

Can anyone give a working example on how to compute confidence intervals for mahalanobis distance (MD)?
I am using R and here is a sample dataset that I use. I am interesting in computing the MD between these two matrices.

```
#define matrix
mat1<-matrix(data=c(2,2,6,7,4,6,5,4,2,1,2,5,5,3,7,4,3,6,5,3),nrow=10)
mat2<-matrix(data=c(6,7,8,5,5,5,4,7,6,4),nrow=5)
```

Before starting with the confidence intervals, I calculated the MD using two ways, a manual way and using a function but I get different results.

```
#Working example Manual way

#center data
mat1.1<-scale(mat1,center=T,scale=F)
mat2.1<-scale(mat2,center=T,scale=F)
#cov matrix
mat1.2<-cov(mat1.1,method="pearson")
mat2.2<-cov(mat2.1,method="pearson")
n1<-nrow(mat1)
n2<-nrow(mat2)
n3<-n1+n2
#pooled matrix
mat3<-((n1/n3)*mat1.2) + ((n2/n3)*mat2.2)
#inverse pooled matrix
mat4<-solve(mat3)
#mean diff
mat5<-as.matrix((colMeans(mat1)-colMeans(mat2)))
#multiply
mat6<-t(mat5) %*% mat4
#multiply
sqrt(mat6 %*% mat5)
```

And here is the method using function

```
#Using Function

require(HDMD)
pairwise.mahalanobis(as.matrix(rbind(mat1,mat2)),as.factor(c(rep(1,10),rep(2,5))))
```

If anyone has any insight on this, that would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Mahalanobis distance is just a measure, not a statistic. It has no variance. If your data are a sample of a population, you could bootstrap to build a sampling distribution for the Mahalanobis distance, though.

Comment: Hmmm.. I just stumbled across this.
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1081/SAC-100001856

Comment: See also [here](http://stat.haifa.ac.il/~reiser/article/mahalanobis.ps)